# issues with a triple loop regrading setting the ranges for the loop

Tags: python

Hi guys i think i am going around this the wrong way, what is the best way in which to do this

this is my code so far

```
  for d in dl:  
    for i in a:
      for j in dr:
        print i + " " + j + " " + d
```

this outprints all possible combinations of i j and d

however what i want to do is for the first element in d to print out the first element in i and then the first element in j, then loop around again while still in the first element of d to print out the second element of i and j and do this again, then once this is completed to print out the 2nd element of d and print out the 4th element of i +j and do this till the 6th element

how can i do such a loop

Edit ok sorry for the description it has even confused me lol

example

```
dl ={ test1, test2}
a = {a,b,c,d,e,f}
dr = {0,1,2,3,4,5}
```

what i want to get out is

```
 test1 a 0
 test1 b 1
 test1 c 2
 test2 d 3
 test2 e 4
 test2 f 5
```

Comment: I am kind of lost in your description...

Comment: Why does it skip from 2nd to 4th element of i and j? What happens to the 3rd?

Comment: I find the explanation extremely hard to follow. Why not include a simple example or two, showing both the inputs and the desired output.

Comment: Sorry i understand that, have added an example which hopefully makes things clearer

Comment: Why are you inputs sets? Is order unimportant?

Comment: input is important it must follow each element in the set

Comment: @user2061913 but Python sets *aren't* ordered; per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset): *"A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects."* Also `a = {a, ...}` doesn't make sense - I think you mean `a = ['a', ...]`, i.e. a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the output you're trying to get, you'll probably want to use indexes, instead of doing `for x in y`. Here's my recommendation:

```
for i in range(0,len(dl)):
  for j in range(0,3):
    a_elem = i*3 + j
    print dl[i] + " " + a[a_elem] + " " + str(dr[a_elem])
```

The `str()` function is just because one of your lists is an `int` list. How you'd print them out would depend on the element type in each list. If it's a mix, putting `str()` around everything is safest.

Comment: This doesn't work on the OP's example input - you can't index into sets. However, I suspect this is because the OP has misrepresented their input.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
for i in range(len(dl)):
  print dl[i] + " " + a[i] + " " + dr[i]
```